# How to extract full icon from figma file

Tags: svg, figma

I have got the following icons in the Figma file and I want to extract them as a whole as SVG, but when I click or control-click the border as well as the play icon, and choose copy as SVG, I only get the border (as shown below). How can I make copy the whole icon as an SVG or if it is even possible?

[image: Group]

[image: How it is shown]

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem here, it works for me. Are you sure all objects you want to copy are inside the group?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all objects are inside the group you selected. Alternatively you can to *export* the icon as SVG.

Select the whole group, make sure all objects are inside the selected group.

On the right side panel, in the Export section add an export format **+** and change it to SVG. Click on Export Group 1 (or whatever the name of your group) and you'll have the SVG with all elements.

Alternatively, instead of a group add all objects in a Frame (shortcut <kbd>F</kbd>) and export the frame. That way you can have some padding in your exported icon (useful to export square icons when the outer bounds are not in a square shape).

[image]